# C# XPath help - Expression not working

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Here is an example XML doc that matches the one I am getting info from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Products xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Products.xsd">
  <Movies>
    <Title>Title1</Title>
    <Language>English</Language>
  </Movies>
  <Movies>
    <Title>Title2</Title>
    <Language>English</Language>
  </Movies>
  <Movies>
    <Title>Title3</Title>
    <Language>French</Language>
  </Movies>
  <Books>
    <Title>BTitle1</Title>
    <Genre>Suspense</Genre>
  </Books>
  <Books>
    <Title>BTitle2</Title>
    <Genre>Suspense</Genre>
  </Books>
  <Books>
    <Title>BTitle3</Title>
    <Genre>SciFi</Genre>
  </Books>
  <Books>
    <Title>BTitle4</Title>
    <Genre>SciFi</Genre>
  </Books>
</Products>
```

Here is my code to get all books with the genre of Suspense:

```
//Get state list using XPath
XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlPath); //Path to my file
XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
string booksQuery = "Books[Genre = \"Suspense\"]";
XPathNodeIterator xIter = xNav.Select(booksQuery);

while (xIter.MoveNext())
{
    //do stuff with xIter.Current
}
```

I have tried several queries including `Products/Books[Genre = \"Suspense\"]`, `Products/Books`, `./Books`, and `Books`. My xIter always has zero items.

I'm new to XPath, so I'm sure it's a really simple error, but maybe not. I know I can get a DataSet with the tables [Movies] and [Books] out of this XML file using `myDataSet.ReadXml(myXmlPathString);` so the XML file is not corrupt. If that helps any.

So, my question ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try single quotes? i.e. Genre = \'Suspense\' ?

Comment: end tag </language> is case changed

Comment: @Rozuur - Sorry, typo. Fixed it. @funkymushroom - I did not. I will try that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlPath); //Path to my file
XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xNav.NameTable);
mngr.AddNamespace("p", "http://tempuri.org/Products.xsd");
string booksQuery = "//p:Books[p:Genre = \"Suspense\"]";
XPathNodeIterator xIter = xNav.Select(booksQuery,mngr);
```

Comment: @Andy, Thanks.  Too bad neither of us can compete with Jon Skeet :)

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for an element called Books which isn't in a namespace. The `Products` element is setting the default namespace for that element and all its descendants. You'll need to use a namespace in your XPath... or use a different approach for querying, such as LINQ to XML. (Personally I find LINQ to XML *much* easier to deal with than XPath - especially when you need to get namespaces involved.)

Comment: Unfortunately I am constrained to .NET 2.0 at for this project. How do I use a namespace in my query?

Comment: @Mike: See theChrisKent's answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon said you are missing a namespace.

You can do this in C# as follows

```
//Get state list using XPath
XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlPath); //Path to my file
XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xNav.NameTable);
xmlns.AddNamespace("p", "http://tempuri.org/Products.xsd");
string booksQuery = "//p:Books[p:Genre = 'Suspense']";
XPathNodeIterator xIter = xNav.Select(booksQuery, xmlns);

while (xIter.MoveNext())
{
    //do stuff with xIter.Current
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With VTD-XML, the namespace is much simpler... you can choose to whether to ignore namespace or not.

```
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
if(vg.parseFile("product.xml",true)){
  VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
  AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
  ap.selectXPath("Produt[Genre='suspence']");
  int i = -1;
  while ((i = ap.evalXPath()) != -1)
  {
                    // processing logic
   }
}
```