# Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml;

```
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
   <env:Header>
       <mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7='http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-4' env:mustUnderstand='1'>6797324d</mm7:TransactionID>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
       <DeliveryReportReq xmlns='http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-6-MM7-1-4'>
           <MM7Version>6.8.0</MM7Version><MMSRelayServerID>TARAL</MMSRelayServerID>
           <MessageID>T*3*T\*4\*855419761</MessageID>
           <Recipient>
               <RFC2822Address>+61438922562/TYPE=hidden</RFC2822Address>
           </Recipient>
           <Sender>
               <RFC2822Address>61418225661/TYPE=hidden</RFC2822Address>
           </Sender>
           <Date>2011-08-15T12:57:27+10:00</Date>
           <MMStatus>Retrieved</MMStatus>
           <StatusText>The message was retrieved by the recipient</StatusText>
       </DeliveryReportReq>   
   </env:Body>
 </env:Envelope>
```

So then i have the following c# code;

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(file);
XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("env:Envelope");
```

and i get the error;

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I would use LINQ to XML instead - its namespace support is far easier to get a handle on. It's not clear why you want to use XPath here anyway, given that `Envelope` is simply the root node - why not just *ask for the root node*?

However, if you *really* want to use XPath, you can create a new `XmlNamespaceManager` from the name table in the `XmlDocument`, register a prefix and then pass in the namespace manager to the [`SelectSingleNode` overload which takes one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx).

There's some sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728409/c-xpath-help-expression-not-working/4728740#4728740) but again I'd strongly urge you to consider other approaches if you can... particularly using LINQ to XML, where a search for (say) all the "env:Body" elements (only one here, but...) would look like this:

```
XNamespace env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
var bodies = doc.Descendants(env + "Body");
```