# Select all operations from a wsdl file using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, wsdl

To autogenerate some documentation (and learn xpath) I am tring to get a list of all operations from a WSDL file.

What I have tried so far is:

```
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\temp\tempuri.org.wsdl");
        var list = doc.SelectNodes("wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation");
```

This gives me the error:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at this answer: [C# XPath help - Expression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728409/c-sharp-xpath-help-expression-not-working/4728740#4728740)

You need to register the namespace `wsdl` before you start querying it.

e.g.:

```
XPathDocument xDoc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\temp\tempuri.org.wsdl");
XPathNavigator xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager mngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xNav.NameTable);
mngr.AddNamespace("wsdl", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"); // this namespace may need to be different - I don't know what your wsdl file looks like
XPathNodeIterator xIter = xNav.Select("wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation",mngr);
```

Alternatively you can use LINQ to XML - see this answer from Jon Skeet: [Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088291/namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed)

But you said you wanted to learn xPath so I guess it's irrelevant.